# Is Threadfence Needed for Cuda Volatile Variables?

Tags: cuda

Volatile force each shared/global memory write/read goes directly to shared/global memory. Does this automatically accomplish what threadfenced does? For example:

```
volatile __shared__ int s;

s = 2;
s = 10
```

Then no need of threadfence between "s = 2" and "s = 10"?

Can we say that for a volatile variable, threadfence is not needed? If not, any example?

Comment: Both of these concepts are documented in the programming guide.  Have you read the documentation?  Why would you need a threadfence between s=2 and s=10 anyway?  It could only matter if there is something else going on, in another thread.   And your `volatile s;` definition appears to have thread local scope. The scenario proposed in your question is incomplete, and your question is unclear.

Comment: `volatile` governs access behavior within a thread. `__threadfence()` provides synchronization *between* threads. The current thread will stall until all writes to shared/global memory are visible by other threads. It follows that use of the `volatile` qualifier is not a substitute for the use of `__threadfence()`.

Comment: Rober, the document describes the behaviors of volatile and threadfence separately. I have tried to compare these two to figure out which one should be used at what situations.  I changed the variable to be a variable in shared memory.

Comment: njuffa, yes, volatile does not specify behaviors of other threads. If a thread updates a shared/global variable, the new value goes to shared/global memory directly. Does this imply that any access of the shared/global memory after the update will get the correct value as threadfence requires? For example, after set "s = 2", any access of s by other threads will get the value of 2 even though no threadfence is called.

Answer (score 1):

For a volatile variable in shared memory defined like this:

```
volatile __shared__ int s;
```

any access by other threads in the threadblock after the execution of the following line:

```
s = 2;
```

will see `s` as containing 2, *assuming* there are no further updates to `s`.  However `volatile` does not cause any sort of *barrier*.  `__threadfence()` [and its derivatives](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) are *execution barriers*.  The thread in question will not proceed beyond that barrier until it is guaranteed that updates to shared memory *and global memory*  (for `__threadfence()`) are visible to other threads.

However, with the following sequence:

```
s = 2;
s = 10;
```

There is no guarantee what other threads will see (except in the warp synchronous case, and subject to further scenario description which you have not provided), except that they will see either 2 or 10 (and again, assuming there are no further updates to `s`).

Comment: This is what bother me. From the description of volatile variable, "s=2" will update the variable s in shared/global variable. Now if any other thread read/write s, will also go to memory to get the value 2 for variable s. After assignment "s=10", then any other access of s will get value 10. The only thing I can think about the order is not enforced is that the two assignments are reordered by compiler.

Comment: I agree that volatile does make a barrier while threadfence does. However, if the order of different update of the same volatile variable is guaranteed, then the barrier does not looks useful to me because threadfence also does not promise when the other threads can see the updates except just guaranteeing the order of updates.

Comment: The two assignments cannot be reordered by the compiler, because the end result is different upon reordering.

Comment: @YangLiu `volatile`, contrarily to memory barriers, does not guarantee anything about the value stored in global or shared memory. It merely prevents the compiler from doing **any** kind of optimization to that variable (no reordering, no constant propagation, no dead code elimination, no caching the value in a register when possible, and so on). A memory barrier on the other hand asks for the processor to actually commit all changes made to the variable to the underlying storage and to make those changes *visible* to the rest of the world. These two concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: According to programming guide "If a variable located in global or shared memory is declared as volatile, the compiler assumes that its value can be changed or used at any time by another thread and therefore any reference to this variable compiles to an actual memory read or write instruction", it seems update of a volatile variable actually commite changes to memory. Am I wrong?

Comment: @YangLiu You're not wrong but it's more subtle than that. Reading from and writing to a `volatile` variable will indeed issue a load and store every time you access it, but these write and stores may or may not go through cache. On the other hand, a memory barrier will flush any changes through the caches, therefore really committing the changes.